# Question asked not appearing in my profile

Tags: discussion

This might sound odd but I cannot find the question I asked in my activity profile. I am afraid I will not find it in the future when I need it. Can anyone explain this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked your question on main, but you are looking for it in your meta profile.  Your main profile is at https://math.stackexchange.com/users/634546/kevin-xu